# Drupal: stop auto flush caches

Tags: caching, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have Drupal 7 site.
somehow - every time I make any change in the site- the caches flushed (all the anonymous users can see the changes).

I want that the anonymous users will be able to see the changes only after flushing the caches manually (by clicking on the "Flush all caches" button in the Performance module).

I tried a lot of thing but with no success. for example:

- Use [CacheExclude](https://www.drupal.org/project/cacheexclude) module
- Disable it in Devel module
- Use [Cleaner](https://www.drupal.org/project/cleaner) module (disable the option in settings)

here is my performance settings:

---

[image]

---

Please try to help me with that!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some custom module which is doing that?

Check out this article:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48600/how-to-delete-cache-after-updating-deleting-adding-new-content-using-hooks

The you can search modules (first check for custom made modules if any) and it they hooked node_insert function as explained in that article.

UPDATE: but by your snapshot you didn't even turn on the cache?!? How you expect it to work when it's not turned on? Turn on caching for anonymous user.

Comment: also after change the checkbox to be checked not working.

Comment: Then check for first part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check **"Cache Pages for anonymous users"** checkbox

Comment: Try with a "Minimum cache lifetime" different than None

Comment: I checked both of the checkboxes and changed the minimum val to 1min. but still not working.